# How to programmatically refer to the desired values folder?

Tags: android, locale

I know android chooses the appropriate values folder according to the locale. But I want to choose it myself from code.

```
 <com.example.typefacetest.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/banglaTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:banglaText="@string/hello_world"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
         />
```

In my `values-bn` folder, I have the String literal named `hello_world` which is used for the attribute  `custom:banglaText`. If I don't set the locale, android will not choose the `values-bn` folder. Now I want to extract the string from that folder programmatically. How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: [ResourceBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) or write something like this:

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.locale = new Locale("en");
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, configuration);
String string = resources.getString(id);
```

In id you should put string's id from strings.xml.

Comment: I dont want to set the configuration.locale as this is not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android